# Snakemake: Make rule wait for full excecution of previous rule

Tags: python, snakemake

My Problem:

I have a rule that splits a given input into shards and saves them into a given directory. E.g. they are saved in that directory in format: **shard_output_folder/shard{1-X}.data**.
Let's say a following rule should take up all these shards and "merge" them, finally producing one output file. Here i don't know how to ensure, that snakemake won't excecute the merge_rule until all shards have been produced by the previous step. My script launches the merge step before all necessary shards are produced :(

I hope some of you is able to help me! :)

Schematically:

```
rule split_data_in_shards_rule:
    input:
        "some.data"
    output:
        directory("shard_output_folder")
    shell:
        python script.py {input} > {output}

rule merge_output_of_previous_rule:
    input:
        directory("shard_output_folder")
    output:
        "merged.data"
    shell:
        merge.py "shard_output_folder" > "merged.data"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snakemake determines the execution order of the rules according to the inputs and outputs of the rules. If you define a directory, and not files, as output of a rule, it can indeed be confusing for snakemake.
The documentation (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs) states:

> Always consider if you can’t formulate your workflow using normal files before resorting to using directory()

A way to be sure your first rules runs to the end before executing the second rule is to use the `touch()` function (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#flag-files):

```
rule split_data_in_shards_rule:
    input:
        "some.data"
    output:
        directory("shard_output_folder"),
        touch("shard_output_folder/done.txt")
    shell:
        """
        python script.py {input} > {output}
        """

rule merge_output_of_previous_rule:
    input:
        directory("shard_output_folder"),
        "shard_output_folder/done.txt"
    output:
        "merged.data"
    shell:
        """
        merge.py "shard_output_folder" > "merged.data"
        """
```

Note: added the triple quotes around your shell commands.

Another way would be to use `dynamic()` files (https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/v6.0.0/snakefiles/rules.html#dynamic-files)

Comment: Thanks alot! This approach works for me